# How to avoid authentication perform when Simple WebAPI call its own internal method request

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, https

I have made an Simple **WebAPI authentication** process
Client Access the API with Headers like

**1. IsClient**

**2. APIKey**

The Client is `Authenticated`  if it contains both Headers,otherwise Access denied.

My ApI call is Simple and does't need to add Header

```
http://localhost/SAW_UMS_v4_p3_Dev/EQP_Care_Manager.asmx?op=GetEQPCareData
```

My web.config setting

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="CustomFilter"
             type="UMS.CustomFilter, UMS" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Authentication class the `CustomFilter`

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;

namespace UMS
{
    public class CustomFilter : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication application)
        {
            //application.BeginRequest += new
            //  EventHandler(this.OnBeginRequest);
            application.AuthenticateRequest += new
                EventHandler(this.OnAuthenticateRequest);
            application.EndRequest += new
                EventHandler(this.OnEndRequest);
        }
     
        public void OnAuthenticateRequest(object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;

            if (IsClientRequest(app))
            {
                // Perform authentication for client requests
                string APIKey = app.Request.Headers["APIKey"];
                string validApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIAuthenticationKey"];

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validApiKey) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(APIKey) && APIKey == validApiKey)
                {
                    // Authentication successful
                }
                else
                {
                    DenyAccess(app);
                    app.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    app.Response.End();
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Internal service call, no authentication needed
            }
        }
    }
```

```
private bool IsClientRequest(HttpApplication app)
{
    string IsClient = app.Request.Headers["IsClient"];
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(IsClient) && IsClient == "true";
}

public void OnEndRequest(object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode == 401)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        context.Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic Realm");
    }
}

private void DenyAccess(HttpApplication app)
{
    app.Response.StatusCode = 401;
    app.Response.StatusDescription = "Access Denied";
    app.Response.Write("401 Access Denied");
    app.CompleteRequest();
}
```

The Client is Authenticated as per expectation

but the *Problem** is: when I make internal process request means when API call its own web method internally then again `OnAuthentication` is process which should be avoided!

I have tried a lot different solutions but don't getting the right Solution

*API TO API don't need authentication because API do no need to add header.*

```
  objEQPCareDataList = eQPCareManager_KLTD.GetEQPCareData_KLTD(strModel, strSerial, unixInspectionDate);
```

`.GetEQPCareData_KLTD` this is the internal web service method where API call itself then again it goes authentication.

***I want to make this avoid authentication at the time when API call itself.***

Or any other alternate way to call `OnAuthenticationRequest` only if client access and if client doesn't add header then how my API responds

**Because if I don't mentioned that the header less request is from API itself call or from fake request or may be the  clients incomplete call without headers**

Comment: this does not look like a asp.net web api, what project type is it?

Comment: This is simple a webservice and i m deploy into local through IIS.